# How to CreateAPIView using the request.user

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm wondering what the best practice is for creating a new model entry with a user based off the request in Django Rest Framework?

Models:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assets")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Serializers:

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views

```
class CreateAssetView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
    <Doesn't seem to work, possibly since user isn't in the json>
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Basically I want to be able to send a POST request `{name: 'myasset', amount: '50'}` to this endpoint and have a new Asset saved with the User field obtain from the request. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

*** EDIT ***
Thought of a better solution:

```
class CreateAssetView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
    queryset = Asset.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

However this means I must send a dummy user_id in the POST request from the front-end. I'm not sure how this can be avoided. Any suggestions highly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since Post "author" cannot be null then we need to provide a user,
one way to do this is to put the user instance in the request.data from the frontend...
the example below is assigning the user instance to request.data from the backend after the request is made!

```
...models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

...views.py
class PostCreate(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    # override this method
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['author'] = request.user.pk
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do most often this thing using function-based views not class-based ones. :
Basically, that will also be able to send a `POST` request and will save the user who requested the post request.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated]) 
def perform_create(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    asset= Asset.objects.get(id=pk)
    data = request.data
    # Create Asset
    asset = Asset.objects.create(
            user=user,
            name=user.first_name,
            amount=data['amount '],
        )
    asset.save()
    return Response('Asset Added')
```

> And to return the data I create another view for the serialized data
> where needed. I guess there would be other approaches I'm sure but
> this one is much simple and easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure I understand completely though. Does the pk need to be defined in the URL? The goal is to create a new asset so the pk is unknown at the time.